# How to make Slitaz USB persistent

Tags: linux, usb, boot, persistent, isolinux

I installed Slitaz on a USB pendrive. However I can't figure out how to make it persistent automatically. There are different sources telling me different ways to make it persistent.

One told me to add `slitaz home=usb` to the *syslinux.cfg* file like this:

```
append initrd=/boot/rootfs.gz rw root=/dev/null vga=normal autologin slitaz home=usb
```

but it didn't work for me.

[The handbook](http://www.slitaz.org/en/doc/handbook/liveusb.html) gave an example of how to do it manually but I didn't try it and I also want it to happen automatically.

There is [an older article](http://custompc.co.uk/features/602451/make-any-pc-your-own-with-linux-on-a-usb-key.html) that also explains how to make the USB persistent but I don't want to try it 'cause it looks outdated (from 2008).

Does anyone know the best way to make the USB automatically persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just bumped into the same thing, so I thought I'd post some notes here:

- Downloaded the http://mirror.slitaz.org/iso/4.0/slitaz-4.0.iso
- Extracted the iso contents through a `sudo mount slitaz-4.0.iso /tmp/iso -o loop`
- Saved .iso contents on thumbdrive; booted

At first boot, one is being auto-logged in as `tux` user; the problem is:

- `tux` user is "autogenerated" apparently
- When changes are saved for persistence, apparently, the home folder of the autogenerated `tux` user is not saved

Anyways, here I tried installing some programs (like `xvkbd`) through Package Manager (Tazpanel - Packages); and to make them persistent, first:

- Right-click on Desktop, Slitaz Live, TazUSB Writefs (gzip)

This will save a `rootfs.gz` file in `/` - this one you must copy *manually* to the USB flash drive, where the others (rootfs1.gz, rootfs2.gz) are - in `/boot` on the USB thumbdrive!

Then, you must *also* manually add this file to `syslinux.cfg`! There is another problem here - if the usb thumbdrive is FAT-formatted, then the autologin command for the `tux` user will fail - and you will get a login prompt/window instead; where you *cannot* login as `tux` (which has an empty password by default, otherwise); you can only login as `root`.

Thankfully, there is a way around this - note first, the default entry in `syslinux.cfg` would be like this:

```
LABEL sli
    KERNEL /boot/bzImage
    append initrd=/boot/rootfs4.gz,/boot/rootfs3.gz,/boot/rootfs2.gz,/boot/rootfs1.gz rw root=/dev/null vga=normal autologin
```

Note, on that line one could also use `home=` for persistence - but not on a FAT32 USB thumb (the login problem).

Then, you could copy the `rootfs.gz` generated by Writefs previous as `/boot/rootfsA.gz`; now if you try just

```
    append initrd=/boot/rootfsA.gz rw root=/dev/null vga=normal autologin
```

... then you again get the login problem (though if you login as root, you'll see the installed programs are there).

The cool thing, is that you can add `rootfsA.gz` along with the others in the `append` line; if it is added at end, then it is the same as if it is alone (login problem) - but if you *prepend* it - that is, add it first:

```
    append initrd=/boot/rootfsA.gz,/boot/rootfs4.gz,/boot/rootfs3.gz,/boot/rootfs2.gz,/boot/rootfs1.gz rw root=/dev/null noswap vga=normal lang=en kmap=us autologin
```

... then both the installed programs will be available (some persistence) - but the next filesystems will overwrite settings; and will create the live user `tux` and proceed to autologin in that accound. So, it is not possible to save desktop icons and such - but at least the installed programs are there. Add `lang=en kmap=us` to avoid the questions at startup (so it proceeds directly to autologin; EDIT - it throws a message on `lang=en`; so it's probably `lang=en_US`) - and I also tried to add `noswap` to deactivate swap; but it still finds my local HD's swap, and does "Activating swap memory ..." (which I'd rather it didn't).

Anyways, nice it can be hacked in this way - though it is a bit of a pain having to generate a new image and copy it around, each time I change a single config line or so...

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: sounds legit. Unfortunately I'm not going to have time to test it myself anytime soon, so I'll mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1):

When adding it into the boot line, drop the "slitaz" as it's already called out.
"home=usb"

Answer (score 0):

There is a menu option that will guide you.

You will need a usb formated ext3. The partition table must be msdos not gpt.  The usb must have 2 partitions one for / and the other for home.

Answer (score 0):

@sdaau @Derek @Yuri Herrera Your notes helped me figure out how to set up true persistence. Here's how.

First you must add a second partition to your USB drive. This partition must be ext3, not NTFS or FAT32. I used Gparted to format the ext3 partition.

Then when editing syslinux.cfg which is now called isolinux.cfg in newer versions of slitaz. The version of slitaz I used its slitaz cooking.

In isolinux.cfg you need to add home=sdb2 where sdb2 is your second partition you created on your USB drive. home=sdb2 goes directly after append but before initrd=

It will look like this

```
append home=sdb2 initrd=/boot/rootfs4.gz,/boot/rootfs3.gz,/boot/rootfs2.gz,/boot/rootfs1.gz rw root=/dev/null vga=normal lang=en_US kmap=us autologin
```

or

```
append home=sdb2 initrd=/boot/rootfsA.gz rw root=/dev/null vga=normal lang=en_US kmap=us autologin
```